# How to filter multidimensional array?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an array. I want to filter data according to their department.

I have tried the following code

```
this.arr.filter((item)=> {
             return (item.NAME.indexOf(value) > -1);
           });

this.arr = [{DEPT : "A"
DETAIL: {NAME:"ABC", CODE:"1"}
}
{DEPT : "B"
DETAIL: {NAME:"TEST",CODE:"2"}
}]
```

I expect the output

```
[{DEPT : "A"
DETAIL: {NAME:"ABC", CODE:"1"}
}]
```

but the actual output is

```
[{DEPT : "A"
DETAIL: {NAME:"ABC", CODE:"1"}
}
{DEPT : "B"
DETAIL: {NAME:"TEST",CODE:"2"}
}]
```

Comment: Focus on the array object's structure.

Answer (score 0):

This code works as you expect :

```js
arr = [{
    DEPT: "A",
    DETAIL: { NAME: "ABC", CODE: "1" }
  },
  {
    DEPT: "B",
    DETAIL: { NAME: "TEST", CODE: "2" }
  }];
```

This code

```js
console.log(this.arr.filter((item) => item.DETAIL.NAME.indexOf('ABC') > -1 ))
```

prints :

```js
[{
    DEPT: "B",
    DETAIL: { NAME: "TEST", CODE: "2" }
}]
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-94s6nb)